# Как правильно рассчитать общую стоимость в Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Дбрый вечер.
Перепробовал много способов, но ничего не выходит. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Имеются следующие данные загруженные в Power BI:
таблица1 со столбцами (ID, Количество, Выручка, Тип доставки, Регион)
таблица2 со столбцами (Тип доставки, Стоимость)

Как посчитать общую стоимость доставки по всем заказам
Каждый тип доп доставки стоит по своему
Без объединения таблиц

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "без объединения таблиц"?

Comment: Не используя PowerQury и функцию merge query

Answer (score 0):

ответ найден

```
Мера = SUMX('Продажи', RELATED('СПР_стоимость_доставки'[Стоимость доставки]))
```